# ASP.NET MVC no linux (mod_Mono, apache)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache, centos, mono

Estou tentando rodar a minha aplicação ASP.NET MVC em um sistema CentOS 7. Após instalar o mono e verificar que consigo executar usando o XSP, estou com dificuldades de configurar o mod_mono no apache. Atualmente está dando o seguinte erro: Service Unavaliable.

Segue as configurações utilizadas no httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule mono_module /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so
Include "/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_mono.conf"


MonoUnixSocket /tmp/.mod_mono_server
MonoServerPath /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4
MonoAutoApplication enabled
SetHandler mono
MonoApplications "/:/var/www/html"
MonoApplicationsConfigDir  /etc/mono
MonoPath /usr/lib/mono/4.5:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/mono/4.5



<Location /mono>
    SetHandler mono-ctrl
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Location>
```